# Does Windows Certificate Issuer not provide a secret key?

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, namecheap

I'm trying to set up an SSL from Namecheap and I need both the public cert and the private key but Windows seems only to give the public key. I even tried using the export option later on and found nothing akin to a secret key (show below):

[image]

Any insight would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Did you initially import this certificate and disallowed private key to be exportable? If so, now you can only export the public certificate, without the private key.

Comment: Your selection will only export the certificate. Select `PKCS #7` if you want both the certificate(s) and private key.